# How can I update my password using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day everyone! I have seen many thread about changing password but I really don't understand how it works. I create a table name `tbl_user` with `fieldname` of `id`, `username`, `email`, `user_type` and `password`. I've search for a complete code for changing password but the problem is it didn't work at all. I already include this code `$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb")`. Nothing happen. How can I change the password who is login? Can somebody help me regarding to my problem? I want to create a offline website. I just need to change my password that's all.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validatePassword() {
    var defaultcurrentPass,changenewPass,RetypePassword,output = true;
    defaultcurrentPass = document.frmChange.defaultcurrentPass;
    changenewPass = document.frmChange.changenewPass;
    RetypePassword = document.frmChange.RetypePassword;

    if(!defaultcurrentPass.value) {
        defaultcurrentPass.focus();
        document.getElementById("defaultcurrentPass").innerHTML = "required";
        output = false;
    }

    else if(!changenewPass.value) {
        changenewPass.focus();
        document.getElementById("changenewPass").innerHTML = "required";
        output = false;
    }

    else if(!RetypePassword.value) {
        RetypePassword.focus();
        document.getElementById("RetypePassword").innerHTML = "required";
        output = false;
    }

    if(changenewPass.value != RetypePassword.value) {
        changenewPass.value="";
        RetypePassword.value="";
        changenewPass.focus();
        document.getElementById("RetypePassword").innerHTML = "Both Password are not same";
        output = false;
    }   
    return output;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<style type="text/css">
    .required {color: #FF0000; font-size:16px; font-weight:italic; padding-left:10px;}
    .message {color: #FF0000; text-align: center; width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="frmChange" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Current Password: <span id="defaultcurrentPass"  class="required"></span></label>
        <input type="password" name="defaultcurrentPass" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>New Password: <span id="changenewPass" class="required"></span></label>
            <input type="password" name="changenewPass" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Retype New Password: <span id="RetypePassword" class="required"></span></label>
        <input type="password" name="RetypePassword" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
            <div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cms_desc['ofid']; ?>"name="hofid"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="updatepass"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Password"/>
                </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");

$_SESSION["id"]=31;

if(isset($_POST['updatepass'])) { 

    $result =$db->query("SELECT *from tbl_user WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $pass_encrypt=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['defaultcurrentPass']));

    if($pass_encrypt == $row["password"]) {

        $passnew_encrypt=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['changenewPass']));
        $str=$db->query("UPDATE tbl_user set password='" . $passnew_encrypt . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
        $message = "You have successfully changed your password.";
    } else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
?>
```

Comment: please do some debugging first to find out how far you get and where exactly something unexpected happens. It's impossible for us to do that.

Comment: _sidenote_: do __not__ md5 passwords. use password_hash and password_verify.

Comment: @Jeff I am sorry for that sir

Comment: the form has no action defined. Is the php really in the same script as the html shown?

Comment: Yes sir, there are in same script. I just separate it so you can understand it clearly

Comment: this `defaultcurrentPass = document.frmChange.defaultcurrentPass;` will not work and throw an error 'undefined'

Comment: First step for debugging this would be to tell us what the result of `UPDATE tbl_user set password...` or even echoing out what the result of that concatenation is.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb') or die('Connect to database'); // 1) connect to db 

if(isset($_POST['oldPass']) && isset($_POST['newPass'])) {

    if (!$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']) return die('No User Session Found');  // 2) make sure you are logged in

    $sql = "SELECT id, password FROM tbl_user WHERE id = $user_id";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); // 3) to check whether users exist or not

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if ($row['userPass'] == $_POST['oldPass']) { // 4) checks previous password

        $sqlUpdateQuery = "UPDATE tbl_user SET password = " . $_POST['newPass'] . " WHERE id = $user_id";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlUpdateQuery) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

        if ($result) {
            echo "Updated!!";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    Old Pass:
    <input type="password" name="oldPass"> <br>
    New Pass:
    <input type="password" name="newPass"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
```

To debug use mysqli_error function.